# Why is unique pageviews higher than sessions?

Tags: google-analytics

Looking at just one landing page, the unique pageviews is higher than sessions. Why is that? Shouldn't they be equal?

Answer (score 0):

A unique pageview is counted whenever a visitor lands on that given page for the first time, whether from another page within that domain, or from outside of it. A session is counted only on the first page visited. Example:

User 1 lands on Page A, then navigates to Page C, then Page B - This is three pageviews and one session. A session for Page A, and a pageview for Page A, Page B, Page C.

User 2 lands on Page B, then navigates to Page C and Page A - This is three pageviews and one session as well. A session for Page B, and a pageview for Page A, Page B, Page C.

Based on these 2 users we have the following:

Page A - 1 Session, 2 pageviews
Page B - 1 Session, 2 pageviews
Page C - 0 Sessions, 2 pageviews
Total - 2 Sessions, 6 unique pageviews

I hope this helps!